# Deducing a derivative from its evaluation at the identity

Tags: matrices, analysis, derivatives, determinant, matrix-calculus

I have shown that the Frechet derivative at $\mathbf{I}$ of the determinant map is $\text{tr}\,\mathbf{H}$. In notation:

$$D \det \mathbf{A}\big|_{\mathbf{I}} (\mathbf{H})=\text{tr}\,\mathbf{H}$$

> Is it possible, *using this fact*, to deduce the derivative of $\det$ at
>   arbitrary $\mathbf{A}?$ i.e. to easily show:
>   $$D\det\mathbf{A}\,(\mathbf{H})=\det\mathbf{A}\,\text{tr}\,(\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{H})$$

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1072438/117749) suggests that we can, but I don't understand the hint that is given: I think they mean take $f:\;(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y})\mapsto \mathbf{XY}$ and use the chain rule on $\det f$ but I don't understand how to do this, because I get $Df\cdot D\det (f)$ which I cannot really make sense of.

---

Otherwise I am tempted to write: $$D \det \mathbf{A}\big|_{\mathbf{I}} (\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{H})=\text{tr}\,(\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{H})$$ but then I somehow need to squeeze out $(\det\mathbf{A})^{-1}$ from the left hand side, and have $D\det \mathbf{A}\,(\mathbf{H})$ left... if that is possible and/or makes sense.

Pleeease can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative of the determinant map at $A$ is the coefficient $a(H)$ in the expansion
$$
\det(A+tH)=\det A + t \, \color{blue}{a(H)} + O(t^2)
.
$$
But
$$\begin{split}
\det(A+tH)
&= \det\bigl(A(I+tA^{-1}H)\bigr)
\\&= \det A \, \det(I+tA^{-1}H)
\\&= [\text{according to the fact that you already know}]
\\&= \det A \cdot \bigl( 1 + t \, \operatorname{tr}(A^{-1}H) + O(t^2) \bigr)
\\&= \det A  + t \, \color{blue}{\det A \, \operatorname{tr}(A^{-1}H)} + O(t^2) \bigr)
,
\end{split}$$
so
$$
a(H) = \det A \, \operatorname{tr}(A^{-1}H)
.
$$