# How to find the 2nd derivative of the logarithm of the determinant?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, logarithms, determinant, matrix-calculus

I have the following function

$$A \mapsto -N\text{ln}\pi+N_{d}\text{ln}(\text{det}(A))-\sum_{n=1}^{N_d}\textbf{y}_n^{H}A\textbf{y}_n.$$

and I want to find its second order derivative with respect to $A$. I found that the second order derivative of first and third term will be zero. But what will come for second term?

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: As the answers below have indicated, the first derivative is the adjugate matrix. But the second derivative is a _fourth-order tensor_  which cannot be expressed using standard matrix notation. What use do you have in mind for such a beast?

Answer (score 0):

It's a [well know result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765757/is-the-determinant-differentiable/765772#765772) (and not difficult to prove) that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a_{ij}} |A| = (\operatorname{adj} A)_{ji}$$

or

$$\frac{\partial |A|}{\partial A}  = (\operatorname{adj} A)^t$$

Hence, by the chain rule and [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#Finding_inverse_matrix):

$$\frac{\partial \log |A|}{\partial A}  = \frac{1}{|A|}(\operatorname{adj} A)^t= ({A^{-1}})^t$$

Comment: from matrix cookbook and also from your solution i understood how $(A^{-1})^{t}$ is coming. But the final answer for my question is $−A^{−2}$. I am having doubt, how the $Nd$ in second term gets cancelled while taking second order derivative.

Comment: The first derivative of a scalar wrt to a matrix is a matrix. The second derivative would be a "4-d matrix", or  fourth-order tensor. I don't know how you can get a matrix.